# I'm having trouble in fetching the data using aggregate function and BETWEEN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble in fetching the data using aggregate function and BETWEEN clause.

```
$statusQ = "SELECT COUNT(total_submit_sub) AS noofsub 
            FROM total_noof_sub 
            WHERE sub_name = 'PHP' 
              AND sem = '8'
              AND dept = 'CE'
              AND laborlec = 'Lab'
              AND faculty_name = 'user'
              AND adate BETWEEN '2019/01/01' AND '2019/03/30'";
```

Comment: What kind of problem?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Are you receiving wrong result or any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $statusQ = "SELECT COUNT(total_submit_sub) AS noofsub 
            FROM total_noof_sub 
            WHERE sub_name = 'PHP' 
              AND sem = '8'
              AND dept = 'CE'
              AND laborlec = 'Lab'
              AND faculty_name = 'user'
              AND convert(DATETIME,adate)   BETWEEN Convert(DATETIME,CASE WHEN isnull(2019/01/01,'')='' THEN adate ELSE isnull(2019/01/01,'') END)     
              AND Convert(DATETIME, CASE WHEN isnull(2019/03/30,'')='' THEN adate ELSE isnull(2019/03/30,'') END)
```

Please Try this Code,
**NULL** Part is also Handle....

Thank You!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$statusQ = "SELECT tsid FROM total_noof_sub WHERE sub_name = 'PHP' 
              AND sem = '8'
              AND dept = 'CE'
              AND laborlec = 'Lab'
              AND faculty_name = 'user'
              AND adate BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' ";

                    $countnoofsub = mysqli_query($connect, $statusQ);
                    $num_sub = mysqli_num_rows($countnoofsub);
```

It will give no. of row, what we want.